# How can you style/theme an element of just one type in react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm trying to throw together a simple phone app mockup using React Native & React Native Elements as a set of UI components. I want to set the styling of various elements to a common theme, so I'm following the example in the documentation: https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/customization#using-themeprovider.

But the trouble with the example there (as it says in the docs), it sets the style of *all* buttons. What I'd like to do is to set the background colour of only the solid buttons for example, leaving the clear buttons, clear! **Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this?**

Current snippet (trimmed to save space):

```
const myTheme = {
  Button: {
    buttonStyle: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      backgroundColor: '#03E0EE',
    },
    titleStyle: {
      color: '#180D43',
    },
  },
};

...

<ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
  <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
    <Button title="Primary Button"/>
    <Button title="Secondary Button" type="clear" />
  </View>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Create a wrapper component for SolidButton and or ClearButton.
Make this wrapper components consuming the myTheme context with style props (e.g. ButtonSolid\ButtonClear).

AFAIK there are no selector capabilities like in css.

Comment: @MichaelBahl Want to post the above as an answer? That way people can upvote it etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper component for SolidButton and or ClearButton. Make this wrapper components consuming the myTheme context with style props (e.g. ButtonSolid\ButtonClear). AFAIK there are no selector capabilities like in css.